# PDF does not support Chinese while opening HTML file

Tags: php, html, pdf, character-encoding

I am getting an HTML file and opening it in PDF format. It works for en, cz, pl, ru languages but for Chinese it does not show characters and instead shows boxes. Please see image. My code is:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$html_file.pdf");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
```

In $html_file I am using:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And the HTML file is perfect for all languages including Chinese.

[image]

Comment: is it just the PDF that looks funny, or does the HTML file by itself look odd, too?

Comment: no HTML is perfect for all languages including Chinese

Comment: Chinese characters are typically encoded in PDF files using a different font mechanism (Composite fonts vs simple fonts). How is the conversion from HTML to PDF done? You say you "open it in PDF format" - but what does that mean? Do you look at it in a browser, use software, do something in code? And have you looked at the resulting PDF file? Can you make an example HTML / PDF available for people to look at?

Comment: in html file i have some content in Chinese language. I just set header & throw output to browser, it is sending correct pdf file for all languages but showing boxes for Chinese language...

Comment: Please post a sample PDF. As @DavidvanDriessche said, encoding of chinese glyphs in PDFs is special.